# How can I merge different accounts for Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

How do I consolidate all my accounts into one? I have this account on Stack Overflow

[image: firstaccount]

Then this one shows up for my Stack Exchange

[image: firstaccount]

How would I add them all together ?

Comment: You seem to have two Stack Overflow accounts - see the help center topic for [how to merge accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: This is the [other account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2612587/user2612587) - log into that and you should be able to follow the instructions I linked in my last comment.

Comment: @Oded ok I followed those steps, and how about the stack exchange account(user2612587) can that modified to show my name or the stack exchanges account random like that and the more personal ones are the specific sites like Stack Overflow, Skeptic, etc

Comment: Once the accounts have been merged (there will only be one), you will be able to copy the details from your [so] account to all of the others.